# Can't change language in Steam API

Tags: steam-web-api

There is Steam API endpoint, fetching APP detailed info, for example:

https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=578080

And it can take just a few parameters:

- appids - id of the app
- l - language code
- cc - currency code
- filters - filter results to some particular part, for example filters=price_overview

Everything was working fine until I broke it )))

I started to investigate, which languages are supported and passed a few language parameters:

- https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=578080&l=en
- https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=578080&l=ru
- https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=578080&l=fr
- https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=578080&l=es
- https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=578080&l=de

And at some point it just stopped switching languages and stuck on English (as default) or German, if I put any other parameter, rather than "en".

"cc" is working and I can switch currencies.

"filters" are working.

But language has stopped changing.

I even tried with different IP's, from my own PC, from my web server and some PHP sandbox services - same thing. The only difference is that sometimes it's stuck on English all the time.

What the heck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer.

You have to write full language name, eg: l=english, l=german, l=spanish, l=russian, not just l=en, l=de, l=es or l=ru.

Don't know why it worked before.